# Recording video of headless selenium browser

Tags: python, selenium

I've been working with selenium in Python recently.

I was curious if anyone has had experience with recording an instance of a headless browser? I tried finding a way to do this, but didn't  find any solutions in Python - a code example would be excellent.

Some tips would be helpful.

Comment: You can find a part answer of your question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51265680)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have any built in way to do this with any of the browsers. Your best bet would be to connected to the same instance of the browser (this is easier if you use the grid server) from another program then just take screenshots at short intervals.